# Gershgorin discs and norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gershgorin-sets

Find a matrix, where the estimation of eigenvalues with the help of Gershgorin discs is

a, the same as

b, worse as

the estimation with the help of the norm of the matrix ($||A||_\infty$)

So, yes, it is a homework. And I'm not asking you to solve it for me (I know you guys hate that anyway) I just don't get the problem.

For **a,** e.g. the matrix

\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 & 4 \\ 
4 & 0 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & 0%
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

has a norm of $||A||_\infty=7$ and there are $3$ discs with a $[0,0]$ centre and with a $7$ radius. So it's basically the same as the estimation with the help of the norm.

About the second one, I'm clueless.

Comment: There are many matrix norms.  Which one do you happen to be talking about?  Or, can we select any matrix norm?

Comment: sorry, I missed that one. Talking about $||A||_\infty$. Edited the question.

Comment: I don't think that the estimation with Gershgorin disks can ever be worse than the estimation using the matrix norm.  In general, $\|A\|_\infty$ gives the radius of the smallest circle centered at the origin that includes all Gershgorin disks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking, but I thought maybe I just missed something.

Comment: Maybe they're expecting you to do something else with the matrix norm?  Are you supposed to check $\|D^{-1}AD\|_\infty$ perhaps?  It might help if you post the exact phrasing of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point which is furthest away from $(0,0)$ in a Gershgorin's disk with center in $a_{ii}$ is the point $$\frac{a_{ii}}{|a_{ii}|}\left(|a_{ii}|+\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\right)$$(easy to prove by drawing this disc). The distance is therefore $\sum_{j}|a_{ij}|$, which immediately gives us that Gersgorin's estimation can't be worse than $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

As a matter of fact, the proof of Gershgorin's lemma involves the reasoning around $\|x\|_\infty$ where $x$ is the eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

We can certainly find an example where the Gershgorin estimate is superior. For example, we can take
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}
$$
(or any non-zero diagonal matrix, for that matter).  As for the other way around: the estimation with Gershgorin disks can ever be worse than the estimation using the matrix norm. In general, $\|A\|_\infty$ gives the radius of the smallest circle centered at the origin containing all Gershgorin disks.